# React-Native-Maps onRegionChangeComplete Breaks & Returns (0,0) and Obscure Lat/LngDeltas

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Some serious head-banging-on-desk action going on over here. We're using react-native-maps and it's about a 50/50 chance it jumps the map to (0,0) when refreshing.

We're using the **onRegionChangeComplete** prop, and after diving deeper, we've can see it's returning an **incorrect lat/long/latDelta/lngDelta** like so....

- latitude: 0
- longitude: 0
- latDelta: 102.73569069743314
- lngDelta: 72.32139609754086

**When it works properly, the coordinates it's bringing back are more like...**

- latitude: 35.78307468033585
- longitude: 99.8066698028755
- latDelta: .072463719198538
- lngDelta: .051887668669237996

The person working on it with me is having the same issue with the same dev, **with incorrect results being**...

- latitude: 0
- longitude: 0
- latDelta: 148.03909769956485
- lngDelta: 126.56251475214958

when the coordinates they **should be getting are something like...**

- latitude: 45.06256685043254
- longitude: -103.290462680161
- latDelta: .0724636120368487
- lngDelta: .056723691523089315

I've heard react-native-maps can be quite buggy, but we can't possibly be the only ones to come across this issue. I've pored over every thread I can find but had no luck. I'm hoping someone out there has had a similar problem and a has found a fix?! Thanks!!!

**Extra Info**

Every time onRegionChangeComplete 'breaks', no matter where we've panned or zoomed to, latDelta & lngDelta are returning the same two numbers. The
(102.7356..., 72.3213...) for me, and (148.039..., 126.5625...) for my partner. At first I thought it was because we're in different locations, but no matter how we manipulate the map, those two numbers don't change (only when onRegionChangeComplete 'breaks', otherwise they update correctly). I feel like there's some reasoning behind the two different sets of numbers that might give us an answer, but I can't find any correlation. The only thing that I could think is that it's creating those numbers based upon our differing screen dimensions. Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks!!